# Why tuples with the same elements declared in different way results in several memory addresses instead of one?

Tags: python, memory, tuples, cpython

I am learning about memory management in python. Recently I was exploring differences in memory addresses in mutable and immutable objects. At first I came to the conclusion that the same objects that are also immutable result in only one memory address for optimization purposes. And mutable objects always receive new memory addresses.

But after asking some people and exploring some code snippets I got results that I am unable to understand. Please take a look at the following code:

```
x = (1, 2)  # 0x111
y = (1, 2)  # 0x111

print(hex(id(x)))
print(hex(id(y)))

a = tuple([1, 2])  # 0x222
b = tuple((1, 2))  # 0x111
c = tuple(range(1, 2))  # 0x333
d = tuple(_ for _ in x)  # 0x444

print(hex(id(a)))
print(hex(id(b)))
print(hex(id(c)))
print(hex(id(d)))

print(x, y, a, b, c, d)  # (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2) (1, 2)
```

From this code, I would expect that all of them should have the same memory address.

Why there is a difference in memory address between those identical tuples?

EDIT: I should also state that I would like to discuss the process in IDE, not python console.

Comment: Using the same address for immutable objects is an internal implementation-specific optimization.  Do not rely on it or worry about it.

Comment: Do you believe they should have the same id because they are equal? try printing `hash()` rather than `id()`.

Comment: I added the CPython tag since this question is about an implementation detail of CPython, and how it reuses immutable constants

Comment: Even the fact that `id` produces a memory address is a CPython implementation detail. Python doesn't expose memory details, and `id` is only documented as returning an integer with no inherent meaning: it's just a value that's unique to its argument for the lifetime of that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `tuple([1, 2])` (or anything that isn't a no-op; after all, calling `tuple((1, 2))` can just return the same tuple), Python won't just go looking through all the tuples it has constructed before so it could return the same thing. (If you wanted something like that, you'd use `@functools.cache`). That's why `tuple([1, 2])` and all of the others return new objects with new ids.

Additionally, when you have Python (well, CPython, since this is an implementation detail) load a module (e.g. from disk), it's compiled into bytecode, and that process does include an optimization or two.

If we [call the `dis` disassembler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) on your code, we see it begins with

```
$ python3.10 -m dis so75512629.py
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (y)
```

i.e. the same zeroth const is saved into two different names, and later on

```
  8          52 LOAD_NAME                5 (tuple)
             54 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2))
             56 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             58 STORE_NAME               7 (b)
```

we're calling `tuple` on that same const (and as discussed above, `tuple(t)` for a tuple `t` is a no-op).

This *doesn't* hold when entering separate suites in a REPL session, as they're compiled separately:

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = (1, 2)
>>> id(a)
4318599488
>>> id(b)
4319249472
>>>
```

However, the optimization does apply *within* a single compiled suite:

```
>>> c = [(1, 2), (1, 2)]
>>> id(c[0])
4319257472
>>> id(c[1])
4319257472
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wanted to ask, you mentioned that Python isn't "looking" through all it's tuples before declaring a new one. But if I will declare huge tuple (but in a "regular" way) it will be optimized. It kinda looks like the problem is in the fact that those tuples were created with a "coding mechanic"? (instead of regular a = (a lot of arguments here placed by hand) (?))

Comment: The only optimization you get out of the box is that any tuple (and some other immutable values) are deduplicated when they're parsed from source code.

Comment: @Peksio How the tuple is created (via literal syntax, by invoking `tuple`, or something else) isn't quite the important distinction. What matters is whether the tuple is a constant known at compile time. Creating the tuple using the literal syntax is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for that. If you create tuples like `(1, [])`, then those will _always_ be created as unique objects at runtime.

Comment: @Brian and AKX Thank you very much for your responses. I wanted to ask you one more question. Do you think that the following sentence is true - "Object needs to include in some way or another a Register Design Pattern." (in order to have a chance to receive the same memory address)

Comment: @Peksio What is a "Register Design Pattern"? Anyway, the memory address is an implementation detail of an interpreter.

Comment: @AKX I might be incorrect here, what I meant is that object need to implement this pattern RDP that is similar to Singleton which basically means that object checks for existence of exactly the same object in memory and if it exist it provides a memory address of that existing object instead of creating a new one. And that would be used in compile time to optimize memory usage like we were talking?

Comment: @Peksio Not really. This isn't related to a design pattern that some class is implementing. We're talking about what amounts to an if statement in some function that checks "am I going to emit bytecode that includes multiple identical constants?" and if so "dedupe them". FWIW, that "some function" seems to be [`PyObject* merge_consts_recursive(PyObject*,PyObject*)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c87537efb5fd28b4e4ee9631076ed5953720156/Python/compile.c#L1246) in `Python/compile.c`.

Comment: @Brian Ah, I understand, thank you very much for clarification. I asked about that because I wanted to compile a small checkbox list of things that are necessary for deduplication. So far I have, objects needs to be immutable, object needs to be a constant known at a compile time, so the dedup algo can "kick in" and that this optimization doesn't work in REPL. I am wondering if I can squezze in more to that list?

Comment: @Peksio I think that sums it up nicely. In a sense, only the second item is really necessary, since only immutable objects can be constants. Everything else is built at runtime from some combination of constants or runtime objects.

Comment: As an example, the expression `(1, [])` from above gets disassembled to three instructions: `LOAD_CONST(0)`, `BUILD_LIST(0)`, and `BUILD_TUPLE(2)`, which mean "push the constant at position 0 onto the stack", "consume the last 0 entries from the stack, build a list from them, and push that list onto the stack", and "consume the last 2 entries from the stack, build a tuple from them, and push that tuple onto the stack". Compare that with `(1,2)` from this answer, which was dissembled to just `LOAD_CONST(0)` since `(1,2)` itself is a constant.